# Excel like filtering in ASP.NET application

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, excel, gridview

I have a already running asp.net (non MVC) web forms application.
It has a gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvPendingInvoices" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" Width="60%" AllowPaging="true" AllowSorting="true"
        CellPadding="4" OnPageIndexChanging="gvPendingInvoices_PageIndexChanging" OnRowDataBound="gvPendingInvoices_RowDataBound">
        <PagerStyle CssClass="gridView_PaggerStyle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <HeaderStyle CssClass="gridView_HeaderStyle" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <SelectedRowStyle CssClass="gridView_SelectedRowStyle" />
        <FooterStyle CssClass="gridView_FooterStyle" />
        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
        <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="gridView_AlternatingRowStyle" />
        <PagerSettings PageButtonCount="10" Position="TopAndBottom" />
        <RowStyle BorderStyle="None" CssClass="gridView_RowStyle" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProjectId" Visible="false">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblProjectId" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectId") %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project" ItemStyle-Width="20%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lblProject" Text='<%# Bind("ProjectName") %>' OnClick="OnClickProjectName" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Manager" ItemStyle-Width="30%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblName" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="10%">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text="Notify" ID="lbNotify" OnClick="Notify"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No Record Found .</EmptyDataTemplate>
    </asp:GridView>
```

Now I want to add excel like filtering in this code... something like this

http://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm#demos/jqxgrid/filtering.htm

I have downloaded this JQuery but unable to implement this on my project...

**Is there any other other way I can achieve filtering in my application?**

Comment: You could try jqGrid, it has an asp.net web forms control http://www.trirand.net/demo/aspnet/webforms/jqgrid/

Comment: I can suggest u to use Ext.Net http://examples.ext.net/#/GridPanel/FilterHeader/Remote/

Answer (score 1):

Since you are open to using jQuery I would strongly suggest DataTables http://datatables.net/ .
This looks similar to jqwidgets (but I don't know that framework).  My experience with DataTables is that it is very easy to use, highly configurable, well documented and lightning fast, for filtering etc.

I also really like the support for updating tables using AJAX, which allows you to modify cells , have the modification detected and automatically call a custom page to execute the update. All asic Excel functionality is supported and the extnesibility is powerful.

I actually rarely use the GridView in ASP.NEt anymore.  I wrote some C# code to generate the HtmlTable compatibile with DatATables.  I wrote the handy extension method below which converts a DataTable to Html compatible with the DataTables framework.  Now I can easily leverage fast client side processing for any DataTable.  It should be straight forward to use the method elow along with one of the samples in the DataTables documentation.

```
   public static string ToHtmlTable(this DataTable t,string cssClass="",string id=null,
            bool includeTHead=true,bool includeTBody=true,bool includeFooter=false,string trIDCol=null)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlWriter x = new XmlTextWriter(ms, Encoding.Default);
            x.WriteStartElement("table");
            x.WriteAttributeString("class", cssClass);
            if (id != null)
            {
                x.WriteAttributeString("id", id);

            }

            x.WriteNewline(); x.WriteNewline();
            if (includeTHead)
            {
                x.WriteStartElement("thead");
            }
            x.WriteStartElement("tr");

            foreach (DataColumn dc in t.Columns)
            {
                x.WriteElementString("th", dc.ColumnName);

            }
            x.WriteEndElement();

            if (includeTHead)
            {
                x.WriteEndElement();
            }

            x.WriteNewline(); 
            x.WriteNewline();
            InsertTableRows(t, x, includeTBody,trIDCol);
            if (includeFooter)
            {
                x.WriteStartElement("tfoot");
                x.WriteStartElement("tr");
                foreach (DataColumn dc in t.Columns)
                {
                    x.WriteElementString("th", dc.ColumnName);

                }
                x.WriteEndElement();
                x.WriteEndElement();
            }


            x.WriteEndElement();
            x.Flush();
            return StreamUtils.StreamToString(ms);
        }
```